# Is there a way to set IBObject to ViewController.Presenter in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've a class define:

```
extension ViewController {

    class Presenter: NSObject {

    }
}
```

Is it possible to set the IBObject to `ViewController.Presenter`?:

[image]

It dose not work.

Or, It can only work in the old way by define the class named `ViewControllerPresenter` in global scope?

Comment: I dont think that will work, if you using MVP mean you create another custom View inside the ViewController, give it its own class, add IBOutlet to it, and make it presenter if im not wrong

Comment: Yes, I use MVP. It works by defined `ViewControllerPresenter` in global scope. I just want to know is it support `ViewController.Presenter` in IB?

Comment: Maybe you can read [this](https://ios.james.ooo/model-view-controller-presenter-8bb4149fa5ef#.ij2zwuw0c) for more info

Comment: Thank you for give me such an excellent tutorial! I know how to use MVP. I just want to know if I can use `ViewController.Presenter` instead of `ViewControllerPresenter` in IB?

Comment: i dont think its possible

Comment: Maybe next year, Haha!